How to make key cursor visible again in kivy text input?
I am learning kivy by doing atm, trying my hand at game scorekeeping app. Making some progress, but a small thing has me stumped: When giving my textbox rounded edges, afterwards I see no more key cursor. As a quick and dirty workaround, I made it so all text is selected on click, but is is still awkward to see no key cursor for when you just want to fix a typo.
Any ideas how I can get it back?
Here is my code:
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class PlayerGrid(GridLayout):
    text_input_str = StringProperty("foo")


class GameScoreExApp(App):
    pass


GameScoreExApp().run()

And the gamescoreex.kv:
#: import Clock kivy.clock.Clock

PlayerGrid:

<PlayerGrid>:
    cols: 2
    rows: 2
    spacing: 10
    TextInput:
        background_color: (0,0,0,1) if self.focus else (0,0,0,1)
        size_hint: 1, 1
        id: player_1
        text: "Player 1"
        multiline: False
        #on_text_validate: root.validate_player(self)
        on_focus: Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.select_all()) if self.focus else None
        halign: 'center'
        padding_y: [self.height / 2.0 - (self.line_height / 2.0) * len(self._lines), 0]
        canvas.before:
            Color: # button color
                rgba: 0,1,1,1
            RoundedRectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                radius: [30, 30, 30, 30]
            Color: # text color
                rgba: self.foreground_color
                    # self.disabled_foreground_color if self.disabled else (self.hint_text_color if not self.text else self.foreground_color)
    TextInput:
        id: player_2
        text: "Player 2"
        multiline: False
        on_text_validate: root.validate_player(self)
        halign: 'center'
        padding_y: [self.height / 2.0 - (self.line_height / 2.0) * len(self._lines), 0]


I suggest using a custom version of TextInput where you can redefine the style for it.  To do this, add a new class (perhaps named MyTextInput):
class MyTextInput(TextInput):
    pass

Then add a rule in your kv to define its style:
<-MyTextInput>:
    background_color: (0,0,0,1)
    multiline: False
    halign: 'center'
    padding_y: [self.height / 2.0 - (self.line_height / 2.0) * len(self._lines), 0]
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0,1,1,1
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            radius: [30, 30, 30, 30]
        Color:
            rgba:
                (self.cursor_color
                if self.focus and not self._cursor_blink
                and int(self.x + self.padding[0]) <= self._cursor_visual_pos[0] <= int(self.x + self.width - self.padding[2])
                else (0, 0, 0, 0))
        Rectangle:
            pos: self._cursor_visual_pos
            size: root.cursor_width, -self._cursor_visual_height
        Color:
            rgba: self.disabled_foreground_color if self.disabled else (self.hint_text_color if not self.text else self.foreground_color)

The leading - indicates that you are defining the style of the MyTextInput class and the style of the TextInput should be ignored. See the documentation.
Then, in your kv, replace the TextInput with MyTextInput:
PlayerGrid:

<PlayerGrid>:
    cols: 2
    rows: 2
    spacing: 10
    MyTextInput:
        id: player_1
        text: "Player 1"
    TextInput:
        id: player_2
        text: "Player 2"
        multiline: False
        on_text_validate: root.validate_player(self)
        halign: 'center'
        padding_y: [self.height / 2.0 - (self.line_height / 2.0) * len(self._lines), 0]

